# Issue when signing up for gmail with proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

This happens after filling out the sign up form:
 - Sorry, we cannot serve your request for a new account at this moment.

does anyone know why this would happen?

signing up through c# app web browser and proxy is correctly installed.

Comment: Why use a proxy in the first place? Is there a case one could legitimately ask Google to support?

Answer (score 1):

Any of these headers tell Google you're using a Proxy and Google doesn't like that.

```
via:
forwarded:
x-forwarded-for:
client-ip:
```